# Angular 4 subscribe cannot assign the value

Tags: angular

[log from web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfVxH.png)  do not know why line 41 is undefined. just want to assign the value to the local variable "users".
   able to assign the value to a variable or log inside the subscribe function.

This is angular code:

```
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {    

  id = '';
  users;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private afs: AngularFirestore,
              private afsauth: AngularFireAuth,
              public Auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const collection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any> = this.afs.collection('users');

    // Notice how the observable is separated from write options
    const collection$: Observable<any> = collection.valueChanges();
    collection$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
    this.getuid();
  }

  //this.user = this.afsauth.auth.currentUser
  getuid(){
    this.Auth.user.subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.users = data.uid;
      console.log(data);
      console.log(this.users);
    });

    console.log(this.users);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It really helps us help you if you paste in the code as code, and not as an image. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It would help if you specified the line that you are refering to because your code snippet only has 31 lines

Answer (score 3):

I assume the problem line is here:

```
getuid(){
   this.Auth.user.subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.users = data.uid
      console.log(data)
      console.log(this.users)
   });

   console.log(this.users)   // <-- Line generating the error?
}
```

The reason for this is that when this code is executed, the subscribe is executed immediately and then the last `console.log` statement. At that point, `this.users` is undefined.

When the subscription emits a value, the code within the subscribe is executed. It is only then that the `this.users` property is set.